# Why do we need CDNs when HTTP proxies already cache content?

Tags: http, caching, proxy, cdn

CDN seems to be a popular way of improving an app's performance.
But why are they required when you consider that HTTP proxies on the web can cache the content already ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDNs are a kind of web cache, just one operated under your auspices, rather than the web user's. You get full control of the freshness of your content, whereas you don't have any control of the proxy servers "out there".

Comment: You say we don't have control but what about HTTP cache headers ?

Answer (score 1):

The user's proximity to your web server has an impact on response times. Deploying your content across multiple, geographically dispersed servers will make your pages load faster from the user's perspective. But where should you start?

Read full article at https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html